# R: Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r, csv

My working directory has a folder called "Testing". However, I keep getting this message

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'NA': No such file or directory

when I run this code:

```
files_full <- list.files("Testing", full.names=TRUE)
for (i in files_full){
    raw_data <- read.csv(files_full[i], comment.char ="")
}
```

I don't understand why since when I run this:

```
View(files_full)
```

It shows two files: Testing/97_2_singletion.csv, Testing/97_3_singletion.csv

Also, when I run this code:

```
raw_data <- read.csv(files_full[1], comment.char ="")
```

It reads the Testing/97_2_singletion.csv in the console.

Anyone have an idea what is going on? Thanks.

Comment: Got another error message, it said "Error in files_full[[i]] : subscript out of bounds"

Comment: obviously you need to use `read.csv(i, comment.char ="")`  since `i ` iterates throw a list of names.

Comment: Mamoun, it works. Thanks a lot! I was so caught up with the previous setting and forgot I did change the for loop condition.